# Как выдернуть нужную часть из строки?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, скажите.
У меня есть строка:

```
<div class="K2FeedImage"><img src="http://***.ru/media/items/cache/3749aaa8ee129d7e919bddcc7e09cd36_M.jpg" alt="Smart Search" /></div><div class="K2FeedIntroText"><div class="content"><!--AdEngine Code START -->...
```

Как мне из этой строки выдернуть тег с картинкой:

```
<img src="http://***.ru/media/items/cache/3749aaa8ee129d7e919bddcc7e09cd36_M.jpg" alt="Smart Search" />
```

Может кто знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simple Dom HTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$page = file_get_html("your.html"); // можно обратиться и по http

$page= new simple_html_dom(); // или просто загрузить строку
$page->load('<div class="K2FeedImage"><img src="http://***.ru/media/items/cache/3749aaa8ee129d7e919bddcc7e09cd36_M.jpg" alt="Smart Search" /></div><div class="K2FeedIntroText"><div class="content"><!--AdEngine Code START -->...');

$firstImage = $page->find( 'img', 0 )->parent->innertext;
```

Comment: А как сделать, если у меня этот html код, вот так выводиться:

$dtext = $data->items[$i]->description;
echo $dtext;

Comment: Я попробывал обратиться вот так:
// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html($dtext);

Comment: Я добрался до тега!! спасибо!!!!!!!

Comment: А как теперь из <img src="http://***.ru/media/items/cache/3749aaa8ee129d7e919bddcc7e09cd36_M.jpg" alt="Smart Search" /> вытащить чистую ссылку на изображение?

Comment: @Дмитрий333332, можно почитать документацию к библиотеке и найти такое решение:  

    $src = $page->find( 'img', 0 )->attr['src'];
но я тоже не люблю читать документацию, как и Вы, поэтому я просто сделал  

    var_dump( $page->find( 'img', 0 ) );
и увидел то, что Вы искали.

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб - использовать регулярку:

```
img[\s\t]*src=\"(.*)\"
```

Более правильный вариант - использовать [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 1):

Можете еще так:

```
$file = file_get_contents("site.html"); //здесь, ваша страничка html
$regxp = '/src="(http:\/\/\S+?(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.png))/'; //шаблон для поиска картинок
preg_match_all($regxp,$file,$arr); //перебираем страницу из $file

echo $arr[0][0]; //выводим результат: [0][а здесь все совпадения, от 0 до n]
//получим src="http://***.ru/media/items/cache/3749aaa8ee129d7e919bddcc7e09cd36_M.jpg
```

Comment: @HA3IK, Проверьте Ваше выражение на тексте:  

    src="http вася пупкин png
Точка- это совсем не точка, а метасимвол любого символа.  


P.S. Не считайте мои комментарии к Вашим регулярным выражениям придирками- просто я вижу, что Вы стоите на пути просветления в регулярных выражениях и помогаю как могу :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, И в мыслях не было)  Спасибо за советы)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Сделал так:

```
            $page= new simple_html_dom(); // или просто загрузить строку
            $page->load($data->items[$i]->description);
            foreach($page->find('.feedimg') as $element) 
            $feed .= "          <image_item>" . $element->src . "</image_item>\n";
```